# Formatting Data in MVVM within Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm

I have a DataModel and a ViewModel working successfully together with my xaml view.
In the view I use databindings.

In my DataModel I have some properties like `Distance` declared as `int`.

When displaying the values in view, I want a formatting like adding a trailing `meter`.

How get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe by providing a property which will return a formatted value:

```
private int distance = 0;
public int Distance
{
   get { return distance;}
   set { distance = value; OnPropertyChanged("DistanceTxt"); }
}

public string DistanceTxt
{
   get { return distance.ToString() + " meter"; }
}
```

Then when you bind to DistanceTxt you should get your `distance` with trailing `meter`. I've also added `OnPropertyChanged` in Distance property so that when it changes, your value on the screen updates.

Comment: @Leparevilo Where do you put this DistanceTxt - TextBlock? How do you perform binding: <TextBlock Text={Binding DistanceTxt}? And have you set the DataContext?

Comment: like I wrote above: My MVVM works fine. I added the "calculated" property to my viewmodel and changed in xaml the binding to `Text="{Binding DistanceInMeterFormatted}"`. This works not.

Comment: @Leparevilo I'm not sure why this doesn't work in your case. As I've checked there shouldn't be any problems. Nevertheless you have simpler answer beside ;)

Comment: I found now why it didn´t worked. I made the calculation (adding the string " meter") in the ViewModel. This goes not. But making this in the Model works (plus adding a property only with get to the ViewModel. What I don´t understand here is: I thought, the ViewModel in MVVM pattern should handle something like this and the model is just a "stupid Container". Am I right or wrong?

Comment: @Leparevilo MVVM is *only* a design pattern. I'm not sure how your code look like and how you implemented it, thus it's hard to answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

you can format string in the xaml binding...

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Distance, StringFormat={} {0} meter}"/>
```

Comment: Works fine. But what if I want to make more complex formattings like when distance < 1000 showing "meter" and when > 1000 showing "km"?

Comment: Hm. Seems not to work. In Editor (VS2013) it´s fine. But building Compiler quits with: `Unexpected Token after end of Markup Extension`.

Comment: @Leparevilo Try like this: `Text="{Binding Distance, StringFormat='{0} meter'}"`. I'm afraid that to implement some logic (meters/kilometers) you will need a Converter or designed property.

Comment: @Leparevilo In WPF the compiler always screams about errors - see if it actually works if you run - those errors aren't supposed to stop you from running the program (I know weird)

and yea, you will have to use IValueConverter..